# Multiply values in a DataFrame if certain element is recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, formula, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to make a program which will multiply the Dataframe row if a certain element is recognized in it. For example, suppose I have a data frame:

```
A B C  D   E  F  G
1 0 -1 2  -4  C  5
4 1  5 7 -0.2 E  7
```

Whenever the F column contains a letter, it should multiply the row using the following number except for the last column: 
C= 2.8
E=1.4

So that final output will be something like this:

```
A   B   C    D     E    F  G
2.8 0  -2.8 5.6  -11.2  C  5
5.6 1.4  7  9.8  -0.28  E  7
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv  

data= pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep= '\t')        
U= data.drop('xyz', axis= 1)

for col in U:
    U=col * 2.63

for Z in U:
    Z= pd.DataFrame(U)

with open('File.tbl', 'r') as  f:       
    P=list(f)
    del P[0]

B=[]
O=[]
for o in P:
    J=o.split()
    B.append(J[:4])
    T=(J[3:4])
    O.append(J[2:3])

column=['A','B','C','D']
Y= pd.DataFrame(B, columns= column)
D= Y.drop(0)
D=D.reset_index(drop=True)
M = pd.concat([Z, D], sort=False, axis= 1)    #Concatenating both the dataframes
S= pd.DataFrame(M)  

x=O
while True:
    x= C = 2.8
    x= E = 1.4

    col_Number = col + '_Number'
    Z[col_Number] = (Z[col]*(x) - Z.max()) / Z.max() - Z.min() #multiply the Z-score rows
```

On running this programme, it shows None and only the last column ie. E. The above formula selects the maximum and minimum from each column and does the calculation. Z[col] is the row value ie. 1, 0, -1, etc. which are to be multiplied.

I've tried using loc method but it didn't help. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research.

```
df.loc[df['F'] == 'C', ['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda x: x*2.8)
```

In generic terms `df.loc[condition,[list of columns]] = df [[list of columns]].apply()`

similarly you can use different multiplication factors in different statements for different columns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please specify what is the role of 2 or you wanted to write 2.8 there?

Comment: @Dustrokes I thought you wanted to multiply the values with 2, if you have to multiply by 2.8, then it will become `lambda x: x*2.8`

Comment: Yes, it's working, can be please tell me how to write this mathematical formula, so that it can give me the result which I want. Your answer is finding the residue and multiplying it, I want to carry out this mathematical process to get the result.  Z[col_Number] = (Z[col]*(x) - Z.max()) / Z.max() - Z.min()

Comment: @Dustrokes if you want to multiply different constant with different columns, you will have to calculate the constant separately for each column, and the use the command individually for each column and then in the lambda function use that constant.

Comment: Yeah got it thanks. Though it requires additional lines, it works, thanks.

Comment: @Dustrokes I will try to see if I can bring it to one line and update with the same

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of the keys of column `F` and the corresponding values to multiply by.  Iterate over the dictionary to select the rows you need, apply multiplication and reassign.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 4],
                   'B': [0, 1],
                   'C': [-1, 5],
                   'D': [2, 7],
                   'E': [-4.0, -0.2],
                   'F': ['C', 'E'],
                   'G': [5, 7]})

mapping = dict(C=2.8, E=1.4)

for k in mapping:
    ix = df.eval(f'F=="{k}"')
    df.loc[ix, list('ABCDE')] = df.loc[ix, list('ABCDE')] * mapping.get(k)

df 
# returns:
     A    B    C    D      E  F  G
0  2.8  0.0 -2.8  5.6 -11.20  C  5
1  5.6  1.4  7.0  9.8  -0.28  E  7
```

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply, I tried this code and it's giving me this error: TypeError: Could not operate 2.8 with block values can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.